# what is the use of passport npm in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, passport.js

can anyone explain me,

why we use passport node_package_manager and where to use it??

i am searching something in website ,then i came to contact with passport.

```
npm install passport
var passport = require('passport');
```

but i am not able to understand exactly ,why we use this?

```
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
  User.findById(id, function (err, user) {
    done(err, user);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Passport is an authentication middleware, used to authenticate requests

here is a link to the documentation: [Passport](http://www.passportjs.org/docs)

the example code you posted is actually cut from the docs itself.

> In this example, only the user ID is serialized to the session,
>   keeping the amount of data stored within the session small. When
>   subsequent requests are received, this ID is used to find the user,
>   which will be restored to req.user.
>
> The serialization and deserialization logic is supplied by the
>   application, allowing the application to choose an appropriate
>   database and/or object mapper, without imposition by the
>   authentication layer.